# Combining mulitple cols names with same starting phrase to one col name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe from a excel file as below:

```
d = {"Id":[1,2],
     "Freight charge - 694.5 KG @ USD 0.68/KG":[340,0],
"Terminal Handling Charges":[0,0],  
"IOR FEE":[0,0],
"Handling - 694.5 KG @ USD 0.50/KG":[357,0],
"Delivery Cartage - 694.5 KG @ USD 0.25/KG":[0,0],
"Fuel Surcharge - 694.5 KG @ USD 0.25/KG":[346,0],
"War Risk Surcharge - 694.5 KG @ USD 0.14/KG":[0,0],
"Freight charge - 97.5 KG @ USD 1.30/KG":[0,124],
"Airway Bill Fee":[0,0],
"Handling":[0,0],
"Terminal Handling Charges - 97.5 KG @ USD 0.18/KG":[0,34],
"Delivery Cartage- White glove service":[0,20]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

I have put 0 but in actual it wud be NA.

Looks like below as dataframe

[image]

I want to combine all cols which begin with a certain phrase as one col and the value for that should come in separate rows. For ex, I have cols above with "Freight Charge-". I want to make them as just one col "Freight Charge" and the values those cols have should be part of this col as values. I want to do the same for other cols which have same beginning phrase like

'Delivery Cartage" to be named as "Delivery Charges" Or anywhere I have "handling" as "Handling charges".

Want something like below:

```
ID  Freight Charges     Handling    Fuel Surcharge  Delivery Charges
1   340 357 346 NA 
2   124 NA  NA  20
```

I have added only a sample cols names. Pls expect cols with same starting phrase (like Freight Charges) are more than 2 with different ending text. So need a generic sols that can take as many cols name with same starting phrase and convert them into one col name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the columns as below (also, last line preserves the column names in order)

```
def colname(c):
  if 'freight charge' in c.lower():
    return 'Freight Charge'
  elif  'delivery cartage' in c.lower():
    return 'Delivery Charges'
  elif  'handling' in c.lower():
    return 'Handling charges'
  else:
    return c    
cols = [colname(col) for col in df.columns]
df.columns = cols 
#preserve the last order of the columns
old_cols  = df.columns.unique().values
```

and you can combine the values as

```
df= df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
```

**Update**: re-order the columns as before

```
df = df[list(old_cols)]
```

Here is the expected output

[image]

Comment: this is not correct. It created a new col freaight charges etc and concatenates all values of all freight cols in that col. Thats not what I intend to have. See the final output. I need all these freight charges col to be called under one col "freight charges" and their value should remain in same row as it was originally.

Comment: @Baktaawar form the output you provided, only difference this solution has is that the other columns (from which new columns were made) are still there, those can be deleted.  I dont see any difference in `concatenates all values of all freight cols in that col.` and ` I need all these freight charges col to be called under one col "freight charges" and their value should remain in same row`

Comment: No. thats not what it is. I ran ur code. It creates freight charges and delivery charges col. But it is string concatenating all the Freight charges cols values into one under Freight charge. 

What I want is: "Freight charge - 694.5 KG @ USD 0.68/KG" be named as freight_charge (or whatever common name user gives) with value 320 for Id 1. 

Then "Freight charge - 97.5 KG @ USD 1.30/KG" col should also be named freight_charge with value 124 for second row and Id 2. So its not part of same row. Its a different user id value. In ur case all goes concatenated for same user for all freight cols

Comment: Like the below answer output is having freight charge on separate rows as they were in original data. Just that it only splits by - and picks up first few words as new col name. In ur case i like the flexibility to user to name what they want. But second part is not correct. Below one has second part correct (at least the cols that are combined) but not the naming flexibility. When I said "their value should remain in same row" it meant same row as in original data. If u see original data, for freight cols, 320 and 124 are in two different rows. I want it to remain in 2 rows under one col name

Comment: @Baktaawar, I have revised my answer as per your explaination. let me know if its right now. Also, please upvote and accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: This is actually very good. Helped a lot. One thing I see is that after groupby it changes the order of the col names and is now shown in alphabetical order. I want to retain the original order.

Comment: I have edited the answer but, First, It is not good to ask another question on the same, as it wont reach many users and its hard to get answer for your question, so better to ask new question. Secondly,  upvote option (and accept answer option), encourages others to answer your question, as it is a volunteer platform.

Comment: No, its not right. It overwrites col but it is overwriting cols wrongly. I am getting cols with diff values but different names with this. I guess once we groupy, it orders the cols alphabetically.Now if u just assign that dataframe with new cols (which is old cols here), it just overwrites the names. Doesn't shuffles the column series too. That gets the data wrong then

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the answer again, can you please check if it works now?

Comment: Hi 

I see one anomaly right now. I have a date col of the format yyyy-mm-dd in the same original dataset. After ur above commands, the new dataframe is showing the values for that date col as 0.0. Why wud that be?

Comment: I tried converting it to datetime but it gives NaT now. I believe what is happening is when ur code is doing groupby and sum, it is taking that date variable and converting the yyyy-mm-dd values of that col to 0.0. This is breaking stuff for me.

df['invoice_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['invoice_date'], 
                                                                 format='%Y%m%d.0', errors='coerce')

Comment: Hi baktaawar, can you try this and tell if it works. Before applying any of the column transformation code, save values in array as `data_array=df['invoice_date'].values` and after all code, restore the columns as `df["invoice_date"]=date_array`. you can then convert and continue with you work on this column

Comment: do u think there might be another easier way? Like I think when we are grouping by using sum, it is doing something to this date variable an making the values to 0.0

Comment: @Baktaawar, I think storing the values and then restoring them is the easiest solution, have you tried it?

Comment: i hv tried it. Thats straight forward and wud work and it does. I was thinking if there is something that can be done while grouping. I believe its group by which is causing dates values to go to zero from dateime to float

Answer (score 1):

import numpy as np

Replace `0` with `NaN`. Drop colums with less than 1 non `NaN`. Split columns by special character `-` and take string `index 0`. Finally combine columns with same name

```
df2=df.replace(0,np.nan).dropna(thresh=1, axis='columns')
df2.columns=df2.columns.str.split('([-])').str[0]
df2.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
```

**Shorter version**

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('([-])').str[0]
df.replace(0,np.nan).dropna(thresh=1, axis='columns').groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()

 Delivery Cartage  Freight charge   Fuel Surcharge   Handling    Id  \
0               0.0            340.0            346.0      357.0  1.0   
1              20.0            124.0              0.0        0.0  2.0   

   Terminal Handling Charges   
0                         0.0  
1                        34.0
```

Comment: Was this helpful?

Comment: this wud pick up the first few words and name that as col. What if I want to search for those but name a slight diff?

Comment: edit the question, I worked out this to the requirements at the time.

Comment: Given the answer didn't have an issue, you just needed it modified to an option you hadn't provided, maybe you should have up voted